# How do I use SafeMode with the MongoDB C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I found that some methods of the official MongoDB C# driver use `SafeMode` and return `SafeModeResult`. What is this `SafeMode` and how do I use it? It would be great to see some use cases - for example, a use case with the `RemoveAll` method of a `MongoCollection`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Safemode is only relevant when writing to the db.

For speed, if safemode is off and a write operation fails the driver doesn't wait around to care. Net effect is no exception gets thrown and you don't know you have an error.

Safemode set to on will force the driver to wait for a success confirmation, and if an error occurred will throw an exception.

Use safemode for data you care about (user accounts, orders, etc).

Don't use safemode for data that isn't essential (logging, usage stats etc)

MongoDB's default behavior is to have safemode off.

Answer (score 24):

From [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial):

> There are various level of SafeMode,
>   and this class is used to represent
>   those levels. SafeMode applies only to
>   operations that don't already return a
>   value (so it doesn't apply to queries
>   or commands). It applies to the
>   following MongoCollection methods:
>   Insert, Remove, Save and Update.
>
> The gist of SafeMode is that after an
>   Insert, Remove, Save or Update message
>   is sent to the server it is followed
>   by a GetLastError command so the
>   driver can verify that the operation
>   succeeded. In addition, when using
>   replica sets it is possible to verify
>   that the information has been
>   replicated to some minimum number of
>   secondary servers.
>
> The SafeMode class has static
>   properties and methods that let you
>   easily access common modes or create
>   your own:
>
> ```
> * SafeMode.False
> * SafeMode.True
> * SafeMode.WaitForReplications(int n)
> ```
>
> The value for "n" includes the
>   primary, so typically you want n >= 2.

I hope this is enough to understand the purpose of SafeMode.

Answer (score 2):

`SafeMode` appears to be obsolete.

The equivalent is [WriteConcern.Acknowledged](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_WriteConcern_Acknowledged.htm) on `MongoClientSettings` (typically passed to the `MongoClient` constructor). Acknowledged is the default WriteConcern in the current version of the driver (2.2.4).

See also [MongoDb SafeMode compare to WriteConcern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816233/mongodb-safemode-compare-to-writeconcern)