# MongoDB server on Ubuntu, client on windows (.Net driver)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

using .Net driver on c# app (ver 1.10) that performs inserts to db on Ubuntu (mongo version 3.0.4, Ubuntu - 14).
Some of the inserts never returns (insert is a blocking method in .Net driver).
the document is written to db collection, but response never arrived.
I looked for this issue, with no results, is it a known one? Am I dong something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660950/understanding-writeconcern-in-mongodb-c-sharp

Comment: does it mean that server on Ubuntu doesn't go over all levels? Is it an indication of a faulty write? (I can see the document in the database)

Comment: MongoDB has different writeconcern levels. So it depends on what parameter you set for your inserts. If write concern is 0, then the driver doesnt care and just continues. If write concern is 1, then you'll get a response when it's written away to at least 1 server.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

Comment: Maybe I'm out of this question scope, but what I'm trying to understand now is -why- wouldn't the server return level 1 acknowledgment. (I have control on the server, I want to figure out its problem and fix it)