# How to add WriteConcern in options in MongoDB driver in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

My task is to create the method **`AddUnacknowledged`** where I shoud add item to collection with WriteConcern.Unacknowledged in MongoDB 2.17 and C#.

In previous version there was that option and the code was simple:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey).Add(item, WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);
```

In current version I am not sure how to do this as I tried:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey).InsertOne(item, WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);
```

But **`WriteConcern.Unacknowledged`** should be option parameter for method *InsertOne()*
and I can't find how to write this as option parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding WriteConcern in MongoDB C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660950/understanding-writeconcern-in-mongodb-c-sharp)

Comment: @Mihail Yes, before I asked question I saw that. Also, answer I got below is correct and it is not written in that thread so we can leave this question too. Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look like this:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey)
  .WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.Unacknowledged)
  .InsertOne(item);
```

Comment: Yes. The whole time I changed the places for WithWriteConcern and InsertOne and it wasn't working. Stupid mistake by me. Thank you very much for your help