# MongoDb SafeMode compare to WriteConcern

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Could anyone say how to replace obsolete   **SafeMode**  with **WriteConcern** ?
In particular I am interesting in   **SafeMode.True**  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SafeMode.True` translates to `WriteConcern.Acknowledged`.

From the [driver source code, SafeMode.cs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Driver/SafeMode.cs):

```
private static SafeMode __true = new SafeMode(WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the new MongoClient type to connect instead of MongoServer.Create. Write concern will default to acknowledged with MongoClient, which is the equivalent of the obsolete safe mode setting being true.